# Why does my site behave this way on mobile?

Tags: html, css, mobile, layout

So I just finished up a website for my mum which I'm going to present to her on her birthday. It's a site with four poems, simple layout, plain HTML and CSS.

It looks pretty nice on desktop, but I want her to access the site on her phone whenever she wants so I tried my best to make it responsive.

Now, when I open this site up on my laptop and resize the window to simulate mobile screens, the layout increases in size which is what I want.

However, when I visit the site on my iPhone, everything's so small I have to pinch and zoom in.

Why does it behave this way? Is it something to do with my CSS?

You can visit the site here: http://www.devericx.com

Comment: Have you used [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)? It must be the best CSS template to do mobile-first websites and it is very easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to use the viewport meta tag. Add this tag under the head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

You can find more information about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).